# Let $\theta \colon \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ be a nonzero ring homomorphism. Prove that $\ker\theta = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\theta \colon \mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ be a nonzero ring homomorphism. Prove that $\ker\theta = 0$.

If I say there is some $n$ in $\ker\theta$, then $\theta(n) = (0,0)$. Now if we suppose that $\theta(1) = (a,b)$, why can we say that $0 = \theta(n) = n(a,b) = (na,nb)$? Wouldn't $\theta(n)$ equal $(0,0)(a,b) = (0,0)$?

Also, why can we say that $a = b$ from $(na,nb)$?

Answer (score 2):

$\theta(n) = \theta(n\cdot 1) = n\theta(1) = n(a,b) = (n\cdot a,n\cdot b)$, because $\theta$ is a ring homomorphism. But if $\theta(n) = (0,0)$, then $(n\cdot a,n\cdot b) = (0,0)$, so $na = 0$ and $nb = 0$. This means that $a$ or $n$ is $0$, and that $b$ or $n$ is $0$. Because $\theta$ is nonzero, one of $a$ or $b$ must be nonzero, so that $n$ must be $0$. As you specify that your ring homomorphism is nonzero, I assume you don't require the multiplicative identity in one ring to be sent to the multiplicative identity in the other. If that is a requirement, then $1$ must be sent to $(1,1)$. But if not, you could send $1$ to $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, or any other number of elements, so that $a$ need not equal $b$.

Comment: Where exactly you used that $\theta$ is a *ring* homomorphism?

Comment: @user26857 Nowhere. It's also true for a nonzero group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z^2$, and the argument above only depends on a ring homomorphism being a homomorphism of abelian groups on the underlying additive group of the ring.